# How to split the value taken in a comboBox ObservableCollection

Tags: java, arrays, list, javafx, observablecollection

In my application JavaFX I display in a ComboBox few users with two tables in the DB ( name and surname ), I store my users in a ObsersableCollection.
But After I want split the name and surname of the actual select user for taken other information about the actual user select in the ComboBox.

How I know the value select in the combobox :

```java
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // Parti Locataire
        SelectLocataire();
        listLocataire.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override 
            public void changed(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") ObservableValue ov, String t, String t1) {
                LocataireInfo();
                }
        });
        listLocataire.setItems(locataireList);
}
```

My class SelectLocataire; where I recup all name and surname that I display in the combo box.

```java
    public void SelectLocataire() {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Cste.url, Cste.login, Cste.passwrd);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;

            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM locataire");

            while (rs.next()) {
                nomUser = rs.getString("nom");
                prenomUser = rs.getString("prenom");
                locataireList.add(nomUser + " " + prenomUser);

            }
            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

LocataireInfo() is where I try to recover other information in the database with the user selected in the combobox.

```java
    public void LocataireInfo() {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Cste.url, Cste.login, Cste.passwrd);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;

            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM locataire WHERE nom = '"+nomUser+"'");

            while (rs.next()) {
                civiliteUser = rs.getString("Civilite");
                adresseUser = rs.getString("Adresse");
                codePostalUser = rs.getString("Codepostal");
                villeUser = rs.getString("Ville");
                telFUser = rs.getString("TelF");
                telPUser = rs.getString("TelP");
                faxUser = rs.getString("Fax");
                emailUser = rs.getString("email");

            }
            conn.close();
            // On gére les exceptions
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        // On rempli les champs avec ce qu'on a pris dans la BDD
        nom.setText(nomUser);
        prenom.setText(prenomUser);
        adresse.setText(adresseUser);
        codePostal.setText(codePostalUser);
        ville.setText(villeUser);
        telF.setText(telFUser);
        telP.setText(telPUser);
        fax.setText(faxUser);
        email.setText(emailUser);
        observations.setText(observationsUser);
        civilite.setText(civiliteUser);
    }
```

So I can't recover by the variable : nomUser because it's the last users in my database si I need to execute : myList.valueProperty();
she return : "name surname" and I want split for after recover other information in my database.

Thank's

Comment: What exactly is the problem? How is `myList.valueProperty()` relevant to your problem?

Comment: I want recover information in my database with the value who are selected in the combobox, so If I have in the combobox John Snow ( Surname and Name ). I want split John in a variable and Snow in a other variable for send a SQL request Like SELECT * FROM MyTable Where Name = ValueInComboBox AND NickName = ValueInComboBox.   If you have any solution for display in comboBox and recover other information in the database with the select user like with the ID, I take :)

Comment: Please provide additional code about the problematic flow.

Comment: I have add more details in the main post about code and description

Comment: Not enough information to help you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.
Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue as it stands you can:

```
// Handle error checking appropriately and probably need a better split based on your possible names
// for example "jon le snow" would not give you what you want.
listLocataire.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
  @Override 
  public void changed(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") ObservableValue ov, String t, String t1) {
      String[] nom = t.split(" "); // "given surname" -> ["given","surname"];
      LocataireInfo(nom[1]);
  }
});
```

But you'd be better off actually taking advantage of a User or Person object:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    nomUser = rs.getString("nom");
    prenomUser = rs.getString("prenom");
    locataireList.add(new Person(nomUser, prenomUser));
}
```

where you use a

```
ComboBox<Person> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.setStringConverter(new StringConverter<Person>() {
   @Override public toString(Person person) { return person.nom + " " person.prenom; 
   @Override public fromString(String str) { ... }
});
```

and

```
listLocataire.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Person>() {
    @Override 
    public void changed(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") ObservableValue ov, Person t, Person t1) {
       LocataireInfo(Person);
    }
});
```